# High-level description of aTM

Tags: turing-machines

If I have language:

```
L = {x | x = n^2 for some integer n}
```

How can I give a high-level description of Turning Machine  that decides on the language?

Comment: Are you the same user from the other question about high-level description of TM?

Comment: Did I post this question twice? Damn sorry, I'm really unsure how I ask on this site.

Comment: Here is the other question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116081/683

Comment: Oh I see, no that's not me.

Comment: The simplest way is to continuously increment a counter $n$ while computing $n^2$ using $(n+1)^2=n^2+(2n+1)$. Compare the result to $x$, and stop upon reaching or exceeding it.

Comment: Huh oh, that's nowhere near what I've been trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way is to implement the following algorithm:

1. Initialize $y$ to 0
2. Initialize $n$ to 0
3. Compare $y$ to $x$; if $y = x$, accept; if $y > x$, reject; otherwise, continue
4. Add $2n+1$ to $y$
5. Increment $n$ by 1
6. Jump to 3

The idea is that $y = n^2$ always. This is ensured using the formula $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + (2n+1)$.